How to open .db in Postgres
I have a PostgreSql(pgAdmin4) and *.db file. How can i open database to start work with it

A database is not a single file. What is in that .db file? How was this created? What do you get when you open this file with a text editor?

.db had no special meaning in postgresql. It is the suffix traditionally used with some other products, but you wouldn't be able to just open those in postgresql.
